# How to have ids inside parent classes with `&` in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have 2 classes: `car` and `car__wheel`
I have 2 ids: `car__wheel-right` and `car__wheel-left`

the scss code:

```
.car{
    // some code here
    &__wheel{
        // some code here
    }
    &__wheel-right{
        // some code here
    }
    &__wheel-left{
        // some code here
    }
```

the css output:

```
.car{
    /* some code here */
}
.car__wheel{
    /* some code here */
}

.car__wheel-right{
    /* some code here */
}
.car__wheel-left{
    /* some code here */
}
```

is there any way in SCSS i can nest an **id** inside a parent class with an `&` which represents the parent

**Desired Output:**

```
.car{
    /* some code here */
}
.car__wheel{
    /* some code here */
}

#car__wheel-right{
    /* some code here */
}
#car__wheel-left{
    /* some code here */
}
```

Comment: Please show the desired output.

Comment: Id must be unqiue. And hence, you do not need to nest it in class. Is there any reason that you want to to do so?

Comment: `.car { #car__wheel-right { ... } }` or `$rootname: 'car'; .#{$rootname} { ##{$rootname}__wheel-right { ... } }`